# Loop through array and display year once, months after

Tags: php, loops

I'm retrieving dates from an SQL query with PHP, and I can't seem to get my head around how to display each year and its months based on this rather simple array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [monthname(wp_posts.post_date)] => July
            [year(wp_posts.post_date)] => 2012
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [monthname(wp_posts.post_date)] => June
            [year(wp_posts.post_date)] => 2012
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [monthname(wp_posts.post_date)] => May
            [year(wp_posts.post_date)] => 2011
        )

)
```

What I want to be displayed is this:

```
2012
- July
- June
2011
- May
```

Comment: loop: keep track of year, echo it once, don't echo it again untill it changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$myarray = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $myarray[$value->year][] = $value->monthname;
}

print_r($myarray);
```

Now you have a array like this:

```
Array
(
  [2010] => Array(
      [0] => 'June',
      // ...
  ),
  [2011] => Array(
     // ...
  ),
  // ...
)
```

**QUICK AND DIRTY SOLUTION**

```
$year = '';

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
  if ($value->year != $year)
  {
    $year = $value->year;
    echo $year.'<br />'; 
  }
  echo ' - '.$value->monthname.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: that's not dirty, that;s very nice :-)

Comment: That is indeed very nice :) I was about to rearrange the array but I don't see any reason to do that. Thanks!